# Type '""' is not assignable to type ''. Did you mean ''? Angular 15

Tags: angular, typescript, eslint

I have red underlined problems all over this Angular 15 project and I don't know how to fix it because it's working just the way it is. It seems like the problem is not actually a problem and just a config that needs to be fixed. I'll give you one example of the problems but all of them are basically the same.

In this particular instance, I have the following `.html`:

```
<icon key="x" size="icon-md"> </icon>
```

and the following `icon.ts`:

```
export enum IconSize {
  Small = 'icon-sm',
  Standard = '',
  Medium = 'icon-md',
  Large = 'icon-lg',
}
@Input() public size: IconSize = IconSize.Standard;
```

and the following problem occurs in the `.html` above:

```
Type '"icon-md"' is not assignable to type 'IconSize'. Did you mean 'IconSize.Small'? ngtsc(####)
```

My guess is I have to disable/change some kind of setting somewhere but where? My editor is vscode.

Comment: Have you considered using a union instead? https://tsplay.dev/NllyON

Comment: You should look into [template type checking](https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck#overview-of-template-type-checking). I would advise against disabling it. Make the recommended changes instead, it's better in the long run to have type checked templates.

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu thank you for the link it's super helpful

Answer (score 0):

This problem is due to strictTemplates flag being set up in your tsconfig.json.
You should use your enum value in the template:

`.html` file

```
<icon key="x" [size]="IconSize.Medium"> </icon>
```